# Omitted a job in background check form

Tags: background-check

My resume contains a short internship (1 month) in a now closed startup.

Due to this I have not been able to get experience certificate from them, nor I am able to contact my former manager there.
So I did not include it in the background check form for a new job.

Now I have got the offer and they have started background investigation, should I tell my to-be employer about this? Or should I just wait for their response to see if they even care about that job?

I only have a few mails of correspondence as proof of employment.

Comment: What was that you did not include in the BG check? I did not get it if you included it or not in your application. You do worked there for a month right?

Comment: Could you explain please what is the "background check form"? Is it separate from your resume and the jobs and contacts listed there?

Comment: Related / maybe duplicate: [Can I omit a job from the employment history on my background check?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/82794) [Advice for including work in a background check if not on resume due to job being a poor fit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/40547)

Comment: The 'background check form' came from a third party  the company uses to verify applicants.I included that job in the application but not in the form send by the third party

Comment: @Dukeling my case is reverse.I put in the resume but not in the background check form

Answer (score 5):

You might want to get in front of this. That is, yes, tell your new employer. Perhaps something like

> You know what? I didn't put [defunct internship] on the background
>   form because I assumed the background check company would be calling
>   them; I cannot contact them myself, so I omitted it. Now that I think
>   about it, the background checkers might have other means of seeing
>   where I worked. If this is the case, they will see that I was at the
>   defunct company. Should I contact them to correct the mistake?

You run the risk of looking a bit like a doofus, but you darn sure won't come across as having something to hide.

Comment: Why not directly contacting the background check company, just saying you forgot to add it? I don't see why the potential employer needs to be involved here.

Comment: @NoBackingDown If the OP can contact the background check company, then yes he should do that (in addition to mentioning it to the hiring company). When I have applied for positions that required background checks there was no contact with the investigators, just an authorization form held by the hiring company.

Comment: Would they even seem like a doofus for simply omitting something they didn't think was relevant?  A resumé is just your sales brochure.  If I put every job I've ever had on mine recruiters would put it straight in the garbage without reading it because it would be excessively long.