# Leaving short term roles out of job applications

Tags: job-search, new-job, job-change, background-check

I worked for Arby’s for about 3 weeks and then applied for a job at IHOP. I got the job and I'm wondering whether it could come back to bite me that I left Arby’s off the application when I applied? Do keep in mind that I'm talking about the application, not my resume.

Also, when running a background check can they see all jobs I’ve worked at previously?

Comment: Hi I changed the topic to reflect the question better, hope you dont mind.

Comment: PS: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/40547/advice-for-including-work-in-a-background-check-if-not-on-resume-due-to-job-bein?rq=1 looks like a duplicate of this question and has good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your resume is yours. While you need for it to be an honest description of work history and skills and qualifications, it is still YOUR sales pitch.

A useful analogy is when your spouse/partner asks you about your day. If you start with your morning coffee and end with putting on your coat at the end of the day, well, that’s probably more than they really care to know. They want highlights, and if we’re all being honest both they and you want the highlights that cast you in a positive light (they chose you, remember). By the same token, if you leave out that you had a lunch date with an ex, they might not take it well if they later discovered that omission.

So, put the stuff on there that matters and that sells you. A three week stint is a waste of everybody’s time and effort, including mine when I’m trying to decide who to call for an interview.

Answer (score 1):

The only people who can access that level of information about you (here in Australia) are people with access to your tax records.  Thats usually organizations like police, army, ASIO (our CIA) etc.  I would assume the USA would have similar privacy laws.

I have jobs I leave off my resume where I was only there for a couple of months and it wasn't a good fit. No one ever questioned it.

I wouldn't sweat it.

Answer (score 1):

People leave jobs off their resumes/applications all the time, for a variety of reasons. They might have happened too long ago, they might be from an irrelevant industry, or they might be too insignificant to include, for example.

When I'm applying for software jobs I don't include the three month contract I had at the very beginning of my career (it's both too long ago and too insignificant) and I don't include the 5 years I spent as a team leader in fast food places while I was at university (which are irrelevant to the industry I'm working in, and came off my CV as soon as I had some real professional experience).

A three week job could easily be considered too insignificant to include, and I doubt it'll cause you any trouble leaving it off.